# A simple hierarchical task list (that lets you cross out tasks) for linux in the Ubuntu repositories?

Tags: ubuntu, software-rec, free-software

I just spent way too much time looking for this. Treeline is very close, but it doesn't allow marking a task as done with a single key press. It's a powerful data organizer and one has to change manually defined data types to achieve that.

I'm looking for something simple: a list of tasks that can be organized into a tree that allows adding children, siblings and moving of items and marking them as done (ideally through keyboard shortcuts).

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [tudu](http://www.ghacks.net/2010/07/02/manage-your-tasks-in-linux/). It's a simple ncurses based hierarchical task manager. It's [in](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tudu) the Ubuntu universe repo.

You can add children, move in or out of different levels of the tree hierarchy, and mark tasks as done. Everything is single key commands. It's fast, straightforward, and lightweight.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [Getting Things GNOME](http://gtg.fritalk.com/). It's a task manager that supports organizing tasks in a tree (i.e. tasks can have multiple subtasks, and each subtask can have multiple other subtasks, and so on). It's available in Ubuntu (look [here](https://launchpad.net/~gtg/+archive/ppa/)) and supports marking a task as done with the ctrl+d key combination (for other key combinations look [here](https://live.gnome.org/gtg/documentation)).